# Какое окончание правильное?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Типичным/ой для этого является  виктимологическая вина" — помогите с окончанием.

Answer (score 1):

Как по контексту у вас там получается?

"Типичной (виной) для этого (случая) является виктимологическая вина"
или
"Типичным (мотивом) для этого (события) является виктимологическая вина"?

Из этого и исходите. а лучше всего так и перепишите фразу, восстановив текст и подобрав походящие слова в скобках. А то у вас многовато неочевидных умолчаний получается.

Answer (score 0):

Вина женского рода, следовательно, *типичной*.

Answer (score 0):

Если формулировка фразы именно такая, то речь действительно идёт о вине. Следовательно, типичной.